# Facebook integration on Android: prompt to select fb user?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm working on an android app which uses facebook integration. However, the nature of my app is such that the multiple users will login from the same device. The problem is, if a user is signed in on the official facebook app on the device, then, when my apps initiates a login, the facebook app gives the authentication. So if a friend of the user wants to login with *his* facebook id to use the app, he has no choice but to *logout the orginal user* from the official facebook app.

**Is there anyway we can make facebook prompt to select which user to use the app as?** (like in case of google, if you are logged in and some webapp needs authentication, it prompts to select which user to authenticate as, including option to login as a new user.)

PS: I know that facebook and the mobile are supposed to be personal stuff and not meant to be passed around. I need this regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Google on Android supports more than 1 accounts but Facebook does not support this. You can only have 1 account at a time on the Facebook app. So you cannot use the facebook app installed to do this.

Instead you use this parameter to open browser window to authenticate the user using Facebook SDK on Android.

```
mFacebook = new Facebook(Constants.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
mFacebook.authorize(this, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, this);
```

In this way you can get multiple tokens for multiple users. And then you can use these tokens to access Facebook data using `Graph API`.

Comment: ok you are right but I don't think there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is deprecated.

### Check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Facebook) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Facebook#authorize%28Activity,%20DialogListener%29)

But, it does work

```
//FACEBOOK.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH should be activityCode
Facebook.authorize(activity, permissions, activityCode, listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the Facebook class, as it's deprecated.

One way to achieve what you want is to use the webview login rather than through the Facebook app. You can do something like this when you're opening the Session:

```
Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(MyActivity.this);
openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
// add more stuff to openRequest here
Session session = new Session(MyActivity.this);
session.openForRead(openRequest);
Session.setActiveSession(session);
```